# Plotting Pandas Time Data

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

My data is a pandas dataframe called 'T':

```
               A  B  C
Date                  
2001-11-13  30.1  2  3
2007-02-23  12.0  1  7
```

The result of T.index is

```
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2001-11-13, 2007-02-23]
Length: 2, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

So I know that the index is a time series. But when I plot it using `ax.plot(T)` I don't get a times series on the x axis!

I will only ever have two data points so how do I get the dates in my graph (i.e. two dates at either end of the x axis)?

[image: Not a time series graph]

Comment: Use the pandas `plot` method of DataFrame: `T.plot()`

Comment: Use `ax.plot(T.index.to_pydatetime(), T)`

Answer (score 3):

Use the implemented pandas command:

```
In[211]: df2
Out[211]: 
               A  B  C
1970-01-01  30.1  2  3
1980-01-01  12.0  1  7
In[212]: df2.plot()
Out[212]: <matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot at 0x105224e0>
In[213]: plt.show()
```

You can access the axis using

```
ax = df2.plot()
```

[image]

Comment: How would you only display the first and last dates without destroying the formatting?